# OS X and Linux terminal: getting around permissions

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, permissions, sh

I am looking for a way to 'get around' permissions in order to execute a .sh file which is used to open my python file (rest assure, the purpose of this will be for a pen test).

I know their is a way to do it in windows powershell environments by typing:

```powershell
Get-Content .\filename.ext | Invoke-Expression
```

Is their something similar to this in the Linux/Mac environment?

Thanks All

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This may be related... see [Why do I have to use sh to execute scripts from CD/DVD media?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59561/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). But its not clear if you are having problems with the execute bit; or if the problem is with other bits like the read bit.

Comment: I don't understand how this is not considered a programming question, I need to learn how to execute a programming command (terminal command) which will allow me to execute a python command? @jww

Comment: The best I can tell, you are having trouble running commands. It has nothing to do with programming or development. And its not clear what problem you are having running your command because you did not show the command or the error message. For questions regarding your favorite command, you should visit [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might have more luck if you explained exactly the behavior you want, rather than hoping somebody knows both Unix and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The chmod command can be used to change file permissions. To make a file executable, you need to add the `x` bit by
`chmod +x filename`

To run the file:
`./filename`